# Having trouble with QTP retrieving values from MySQL database

Tags: mysql, vbscript, qtp

I am working on a database checkpoint of a QTP test case. Firstly the script queries the first row of table `timesheet` and retrieves the value of the column `departmentCode`. Then it queries the table `department`, retrieves the value of column `name` based on the value of `departmentCode`. After that it compares the value of `name` with the value in QTP's local datatable.

```vb
strCurrentEnv="localhost"
dbName="timex"
strConnection = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver}; Server=" & strCurrentEnv & "; DATABASE="& dbName& ";uid=root; pwd="
Set conn=CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open strConnection

queryDepCode="Select departmentCode from timesheet where timesheetId=1"
Set exDepCode=conn.Execute(queryDepCode)
depCode=exDepCode.GetString
print depCode

queryDepName="select name from department where departmentCode="&depCode
Set exDepName=conn.Execute(queryDepName)
depName=exDepName.GetString
print depName

print DataTable("department", dtLocalsheet)

If depName=DataTable("department", dtLocalsheet) Then
print "equals"
Else
print "not equal"
End If
```

The value of `depCode` is 'CS', `depName` is 'Customer Support', `DataTable("department", dtLocalsheet)` is also 'Customer Support'.

I have two issues with this test case at this moment.

1. When I run this script, QTP returns an error

   > [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver][mysqld-5.1.41]Unknown column 'CS' in 'where clause'
   >
   > Line (30): "Set exDepName=conn.Execute(queryDepName)".

   I have no idea what it means. Unknown column 'CS'? The output of `depCode` is `CS`, the second row of `department` table has a `departmentCode` of 'CS' and a `name` of 'Customer Support'.
2. I changed the statement

   ```vb
   queryDepName="select name from department where departmentCode="&depCode
   ```

   to

   ```vb
   queryDepName="select name from department where departmentCode='CS'"
   ```

   This time QTP returns no error, but the output is

   ```
   CS
   Customer Support
   Customer Support
   not equal
   ```

I do not understand, how could they be not equal while the outputs are exactly the same?

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why not do a SQL `JOIN` on `timesheet` and `department` against `departmentCode`? would save a lot of unnecessary back and forth. I confess I don't know MySQL that well but [assume it can do `JOIN`s](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html).

Comment: As for the initial error `Unknown column 'CS'` this is exactly what it says, because you pass `... departmentCode="&depCode` which is passed to MySQL as `... departmentCode=CS` MySQL rightly assumes `CS` is a column because strings need to be defined using quotes (`'`), but as `CS` isn't a column but actually a string value `'CS'` if will never find the column hence the error.

Comment: As for why they are no equal, you don't include the definition of the function `DataTable("department", dtLocalsheet)` so I can't really help. `DataTable()` isn't an in-built function in VBScript so assuming you have the definition, could you [update the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35459024/edit) to include it? Have you tried `If Trim(depName)=Trim(DataTable("department", dtLocalsheet)) Then` to discount trailing spaces?

Comment: @Lankymart Thank you for your answer. So I am trying to add single quotes to depCode but it seems depCode has a new line in it that I can't remove. With this 'depCode=Replace(chr(39)&exDepCode.GetString&chr(39), vbCrLf, "")', the output of depCode is 'CS(new line here)'. Also tried `Trim`, same result.

Comment: Sorry don't understand what all that `Replace()` code is for that is why I asked what `DataTable()` function does. If you are doing that replace it explains why the `not equal` is shown so shouldn't be a surprise.

Comment: @Lankymart The `DataTable()` is a QTP's built-in object for parameterization , the statement simply retrieves the value from that column, here is an example [link](http://qtp.blogspot.ca/2009/03/qtp-reading-from-datatable.html). I guess the problem lies in `GetString`, since it always appends a new line to the returned string, which I can't remove with `Trim` or something else.

Comment: I hadn't spotted that why you using `GetString`? You could just use `exDepName(0)` to get the field from the `ADODB.Recordset`. You get a `vbCrLf` on the end of your string is because it's the default row delimiter for [`GetString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676975(v=vs.85).aspx) as it's designed to return multiple rows and delimiter them accordingly.

Comment: @Lankymart OK finally it solves everything :) Thank you very much, Lankymart. That was my bad, I don't know `ADODB.Recordset` very well.